# Security Policy Docker Kubernetes CAP_NET_ADMIN

Tags: docker, security, kubernetes, yaml, minikube

I have a problem and i don't know why it's working with docker,
when i run:
`docker run --cap-add NET_ADMIN --name pacman -d -p 8080:80 pacman`
my program it's working. but when i load my program with minikube and this deployment file:   deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pacman
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pacman
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pacman
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pacman
        image: docker.io/kelysa/pacman:lastest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add: ["NET_ADMIN"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "60"
            requests:
              cpu: 10m
```

i add the same policy group and i don't know why my program doesn't work. i have bug like : 
`WARN[0000] Can't run iptables : Error running bash command iptables -L: exit status 1. Output: iptables: Operation not supported.`
`WARN[0000] BLOCK_NETWORK requires iptables. CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_NET_ADMIN+ capability is also required.`

If i run docker without --cap-add NET_ADMIN, i have the same problem so i add NET_ADMIN and it's work on docker with a dockerfile but it's doesn't work on my deployment.yml.

Could you help me please ?

Comment: So as I understood you are trying to deal with iptables from inside your custom image - as described  by the error:
`LOCK_NETWORK requires iptables. CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_NET_ADMIN+ capability is also required.`
I have just found pretty command to see all capabilities from `inside your container`  
`docker run --rm -it alpine sh -c 'apk add -U libcap; capsh --print' `

Comment: Current: = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read+eip